# What are needed {is/are} managers with new ideas and the will to apply them

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

According to the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddleston and Pullum (page 505), the following sentence is grammatical with either "is" or "are" as the verb of the main clause:

> *What are needed **is/are** managers with new ideas and the will to apply them.*

I'd just like to know how many native speakers, which I'm not by the way, would actually use "is" over "are" in this particular sentence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a poll of "native" speakers and not a question about English.

Answer (score 2):

To my (American) ear, this sentence would sound best as:

> What **is** needed **are** managers with new ideas and the will to apply them.

I can rationalize these choices based on combining these three sentences (or fragments thereof):

> There **is one** main problem.
>
> The solution **is**….
>
> There **are** managers who have new ideas and the will to apply them.

Comment: Actually, your sentence is also listed in CGEL as a grammatical one, along with the OP's. But I haven't shown that sentence in the OP, because I don't have any problem with it. I'm only interested in the OP's sentence. So please edit your answer to show your take on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it's "what are needed" that sounds weird.

As for the rest of the sentence,

> What is needed **are** managers with new ideas and the will to apply
>   them.

Here, the verb *are* corresponds to the subject *managers*. So this sentence is correct by all means.

> What is needed **is** managers with new ideas and the will to apply
>   them.

It seems that provided you agree that the verb *is* also corresponds to the subject *what is needed*, this sentence can't be called ungrammatical.

Also, in choosing between the two there's also a [subject-verb agreement rule referring to the collective nouns](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp), *depending on the speaker's intent*:  Should new engineers be regarded as just several ones or a particular, separate group of *engineers with new ideas and the will to apply them*?

No matter whatever possible discussion might follow all this, to this post it's sooner the usage in speech that matters, and variant A seems to be much preferable:

> "What is needed are managers with new ideas and the will to apply
>   them".

.

Comment: Tend to disagree slightly. The subject is the phrase "what is/are needed". The verb should agree with this subject. The "managers" is a subject complement, and verbs don't have to agree in number with a complement. I prefer "What is needed are managers...". But I would not say that "What is needed is..." is ungrammatical

Comment: @JamesK - Thanks awfully for giving me the clue to better understanding the issue but you, too, wouldn't use the variant with "is managers", would you?

Comment: I probably wouldn't, for semantic, not grammatical reasons. I would say, for example "A football team is 11 players". But "are" would also be correct there. So "... is managers..." is grammatically correct.